# Callback mechanism in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, callback, return

I am trying to understand the callback mechanism in javascript(typescript). If I have a function which expects a callback as input argument, do I have to explicitly use a return statement to hook it up with the actually callback implementation form the calling code OR we can simply have use "callback" reference in the code being called and it automatically hooks up with callback code in the calling code

**Code samples (typecript)**

```
// callback code being hooked up using return statement
clear(collectionName: string, callback: any) {
        this.getConnection((err, db) => {
            if (!db)
                return callback(err, null);
            db.collection(collectionName).remove();
        });
    return callback();
    }


// callback code being hooked up using reference to reserved callback keyword for automatic hook up with calling code
clear(collectionName: string, callback: any) {
        this.getConnection((err, db) => {
            if (!db)
                return callback(err, null);
            db.collection(collectionName).remove({}, callback);
        });
    }
```

Comment: If `getConnection` is async, the first example fires the `callback` *before* `remove` is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to return, you can simply call it like

```
clear(collectionName: string, callback: any) {
        this.getConnection((err, db) => {
            if (!db)
                callback(err, null);
            db.collection(collectionName).remove();
        });
    return callback();
    }


// callback code being hooked up using reference to reserved callback keyword for automatic hook up with calling code
clear(collectionName: string, callback: any) {
        this.getConnection((err, db) => {
            if (!db)
                callback(err, null);
            db.collection(collectionName).remove({}, callback);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Functions are first-class citizens in Javascript thus you can use them as a normal variables and pass them all around. You just need to call them (as normal functions) at proper moments. No return statement required. For example look at how `Array.prototype.forEach` works under the hood. It accepts the callback as a parameter that gets currently iterated element as a first argument and current index as a second argument:

```
Array.prototype.forEach = function(callback) {
  for(i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (callback) callback(this[i], i)
  }
}
```